# HIDE variables from google using mod rewrite

Tags: php, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I noticed that google indexes my pages with the variables in the URL and others pages without them. These other pages do not have variables in them and are indexed fine without the php extension.

For example:

**mydomain.com/page.php?name=flinstones**

my htaccess rewrites that to:

**mydomain.com/flinstones**

But it still shows as the former in google search and google analytics.

Is there a way to force it to show/browse only the pretty urls?

Here's my code.. first part works but the redirect doesn't. 
**How do I make it work?**

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^([^/\.]+)/?$ page.php?name=$1 [L]

RewriteRule ^page.php?name=([^/\.]+)/?$ /$1  [R=301,L]
```

Thanks,

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, never make google see the ugly link! In your php/html code, always use only the nice form of it. Then google stands no chance :-)

Comment: And you can consider to create 301 redirects that redirect the indexed bad URLs to the pretty URLs. That way you can preserve the pagerank for your already indexed pages while removing them from the Google index.

Comment: @Jan-Henk, yes, good note! With just a normal redirect he would have to wait longer time I guess.

Comment: Yes ofcourse i'm using only the pretty urls for my links on the site. Is it as simple as adding `[R=301,L]` to my rule `RewriteRule ^([^/\.]+)/?$ page.php?name=$1 [L] ` and that should fix it?

Comment: @checkenginelight, NO! This is the rule which makes the ugly URL for you, but this must be internal only. You have to add a new rule, which rewrites the ugly URL to the nice one, and this rule will use the `R=301` attribute.

Comment: Could you give an example of what the new rule should be?

Comment: Basically you would start by swapping the parameters like this: `RewriteRule page.php?name=$1 ^([^/\.]+)/?$ [R=301,L]` . Of course now the regex has to go on the left and the `$1` has to be moved to the right. There are probably more changes to make.

Comment: @checkenginelight: See [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7796421/301-redirect-url-with-variable/7796513#7796513) (and the comments under it).

Answer (score 4):

Yes, you can tell Google what the [canonical link](http://googlewebmastercentral.blogspot.com/2009/02/specify-your-canonical.html) is for a page.

```
<link rel="canonical" href="http://mydomain.com/flinstones" />
```

Comment: Would this have an advantage over 301 redirects or is it better to use both?

Comment: This and a 301 redirect will have similar results. Each has its advantages. Canonical will catch URLs you didn't realize were out there. 301s will physically redirect the user (so they see the nice URL) and may have better results for non-Google search engines. Ultimately, you could use both.

Comment: thanks! I would like to get my 301 redirect working first. :)

Answer (score 0):

Mod rewrite means: 
If a page request occurs with this form 'xxxxx'
Manage it as it was 'yyyyy'
And do inform anything to the requester.
So in your case google thinks that both urls are valid (and duplicated), ouch!
For your case use a `301 redirect` that means: 'xxxxx' is not a valid request (or deprecated), please requester (google or anyone) use insetead 'yyyyy'. then 'xxxxx' will be forgotten soon.
On the other hand, it is correct to `mod rewrite` your opposite case:
mydomain.com/flinstones
rewrited to:
mydomain.com/page.php?name=flinstones
to honour SEO rules and to let php manage the request.