# 301 redirect URL with variable

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite, redirect

I want to use htaccess to 301 redirect (not rewrite) urls like:

> brands.php?brand=Sony

to

> brands/Sony

How can i do that? Appreciate your help in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So your users are entering `brands.php?brand=Sony` into their browser, and being redirected? If I have that correct, it's simple:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} brand=([^&]+) [NC]
RewriteRule brands\.php brands/%1 [L,R=301]
```

Comment: its good thank you, but instead redirecting to /brand/Sony, it goes to /brand/Sony?brand=Sony. Is it possible to remove ?brand=Sony?

Comment: @user999516 You don't also have the `[QSA]` flag in there do you? That doesn't make sense - the old query string doesn't get added unless `[QSA]` is added.

Comment: understand, i will ask server admin if QSA is in the Apache httpd.conf. Many thanks for your help!

Comment: @user999516 `[QSA]` is  a flag added to the rewrite rule, not an apache configuration setting.

Comment: oh i found the solution: you must append **?** to the end of the rewrite rule to force to not add the string like RewriteRule brands\.php brands/%1?